# Development Tools like PL/SQL Developer for IBM DB2 for i (iSeries)

Tags: plsql, db2, ibm-midrange, udb

I am exprienced in working with PL/SQL Developer on Oracle.

Now I have a customer, where I need to write some stored procedures on an IBM DB2 for i (formerly known as DB2 UDB for iSeries, AS400).

Is there for IBM DB2 a tool like PL/SQL Developer where I can develop an debug stored procedures( step in, step out, view variables)

What tools use the db2 development guys?

Thank you
Oliver

Comment: Kindly mark the correct answer, marking the answer helps others and your reputation also increases. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [IBM Data Studio](http://www-142.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/data-studio)

> IBM® Data Studio provides an integrated, modular environment for
>   database development and administration of IBM DB2® for Linux, UNIX
>   and Windows. It also offers collaborative database development tools
>   for IBM DB2 for z/OS®, IBM DB2 for i, and IBM Informix®. This software
>   is available at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio is what you are looking for. It can be found on IBM's developerWorks site and it is a free download.

Answer (score 0):

For those working with DB2 for i (AS/400, iSeries and later), IBM Data Studio can be worth obtaining and learning. It has numerous useful development features. But for debugging, you'll need to do a lot of learning to get it to work at all (if ever). Data Studio can be used for debugging if IBM i 6.1 or 7.1 is on the server and DB2 Group PTF level is at least up to mid-2013 levels. (V5R4 might also be possible, though there are contradictory statements at IBM sites; and I've seen no indication of needed PTFs.)

While trying to use Data Studio for debugging, you'll have results much sooner by downloading and installing iSeries Navigator from the server. Make sure that the minimum install includes the 'Database' component. (Not 'Data Transfer' which is essentially unrelated and requires licensing.) The 'Database' component gives access to 'Run SQL scripts' for AS/400 databases, and includes connections to the system graphical debugger.

Many other direct database functions are also included. The iNav feature downloads, installs and configures quite a bit faster than Data Studio. It's also easier to learn and fits better on smaller monitors. (Be aware that a recent iNav fix pack should also be applied.) But it is not a truly high-level database IDE. It simply provides the needed features for much of the database work other than *major project* development.

If you have no control over the fix levels on the server, or the server version isn't current, you might have no other good choice, especially for debugging of stored procs, etc.